# io.restassured.internal.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found

Tags: java

I am a new Java learner and looking forward to developing automation test engineering skills. I am currently having a boot camp for this purpose. I want to solve a problem with your bits of help. We are trying to send a request for a negative scenario like this;

```
When 
  I send a GET Request to the URL https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/1001
Then 
  HTTP Status code should be 404
And  
  Status Line should be HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Although we have the same code with our instructor as this;

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;

public class GetRequest02 {
    @Test
    public void get01() {
    String url = "https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com/booking/1001";
    Response response = given().
                                accept(ContentType.JSON).
                            when().
                                get(url);
        response.prettyPrint();
        response.
                then().
                assertThat().
                statusCode(404).
                statusLine("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    }
}
```

He gets green, but some of us get red with this message ;

`io.restassured.internal.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found`

We could not find the solution? Can somebody help us?

Thank you for your interest...

Comment: It would help if we could have some more details , for instance what is throwing the error ? Have you got the right jar on your classpath ?

Comment: @selim did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

on pom.xml, after   `

```
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

`  type

```
 <argLine>-Duser.language=en</argLine>

         and retry.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).